# Pulling Unicode Data from a DataGrid in LiveCode

Tags: unicode, livecode

We're translating our app into Japanese and have been struggling to get UTF-16 text from a DataGrid. We've tried all sorts of combinations of uniEncode, uniDecode on the data and it all comes out garbled. We first overrode the DataGrid, so we can see that the Japanese in the datagrid is correct. But, when we pull it out using GetDataOfLine or dgDataOfLine and then try to decode it, it is garbled. Current thinking is that we need to create another handler like GetUnicodeDataOfLine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datagrid doesn't modify the dgData unless the user edits something at which point it's up to you to get the unicodeText of the field editor. If you are using dgText though I'm not sure what it will do.

---

**EDIT**

The uni functions always expect UTF16. So the second parameter is what you are coming from in uniEncode and what you want to go to in uniDecode. So uniDecode(var,"UTF8") takes UTF16 data and returns UTF8 data. uniEncode(var,"UTF8") takes UTF8 data and returns UTF16 data.

Comment: 1) Are you populating the data grid with an array containing UTF-16 data?
UTF 8, I overrode the default behavior and when I FillInData: 
       `set the unicodetext of the long ID of me to uniencode(pData, "utf8") ` and this works great. But, when I tried converting to UTF-16, then it is garbled.

        `set the unicodetext of the long ID of me to uniencode(pData, "utf16")`

2) What conversions are you trying to run on the data when you pull it out
with GetDataOfLine?
  `put uniDecode(uniEncode(tVar, "UTF16")) into tVar`
We basically want to compare UTF-16 strings.

Comment: If your data is UTF8 then uniEncode(pData,"utf8") turns it into utf16 in host byte order so uniEncode(pData,"utf16") doesn't make any sense. If your dgData is utf8 then uniEncode(var,"utf8") should turn it into utf16 on both in and out of the datagrid.

Comment: Perfect! I've been having a lot of trouble figuring Unicode. Thank you! Now I'm trying to encode UTF16 into UTF8 to prepare it for a Twitter post. What would be the best way to convert back from UTF16 to UTF8? `uniDecode(var,"UTF16")`?

Comment: You've got to remember that the uni commands always expect UTF16. So the second parameter is what you are coming from in uniEncode and what you want to go to in uniDecode. So uniDecode(var,"UTF8")

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Now I've tried put mobileControlGet("input", "unicodeText") into tText
         put uniDecode(tText,"UTF8") into tText

Comment: If the answer resolved your problem you can accept (click the tick) so others know it worked for you.